# Using Amazon's EC2 service for storing video feeds and subsequent playback for client

Tags: video, amazon-s3, video-streaming

We're planning to setup a server to record videos and save them using Amazon's S3 service.

Subsequently we need to provide a mechanism to end users to view those videos online.

Is it possible to store files on S3 in such a way that they are streamed to user's browsers, in a way similar to how video is visible on youtube?

We haven't made a call on the video format storage mechanism so that decision is still open. Inputs on that (which enable the above) are welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CloudFront supports streaming FLV with Flash Media Server, and also means that your video is served from the location nearest to the user rather than from the single region you chose to create your S3 bucket in. Here's [Amazon's documentation on streaming](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonCloudFront/2010-06-01/DeveloperGuide/).